# Android ListView setOnItemClickListener (setText Button) not working

Tags: android, android-studio

I can not set the name of the selected object in "BarraNome" how can I do?

```
public class MainActivity2Activity extends Activity {

String[] lista1 = { "JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUNE", "JULY","AUG", "SEPT", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC" };

Button BarraNome;
private ListView lista;
private ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity2);

    lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listacompleta);
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lista1);
    lista.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int pos,long id){
```

Look this part of code!

```
            //This code works//
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+ lista1[pos], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            //Don't works, why?//
            BarraNome.setText(""+ lista1[pos]);
        }});}}
```

Please help me

Comment: Have you initialised BarraNome anywhere?

Comment: I was convinced to have put hahha lol


Thx man

Answer (score 0):

1. Next time post a stacktrace.
2. From what  you've posted you never assign your button like this:

   BarraNome = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yourButton);

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class MainActivity2Activity extends Activity {

    String[] lista1 = { "JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUNE", "JULY","AUG", "SEPT", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC" };

    Button BarraNome;
    private ListView lista;
    private ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity2);
//please intialize button
    **BarraNome=(Button)findViewById(R.id.your_button_id);**
        lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listacompleta);
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lista1);
        lista.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int pos,long id){
```

/////////////////// then set

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+ lista1[pos], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            //Don't works, why?//
            BarraNome.setText(""+ lista1[pos]);
        }});}}
```